The DropDown is not opening while recording the script
I have matched the port number in Chrome and J meter as well and also started recording the script, the script is getting recorded but while coming to drop down the drop down are not opening only while recording
Need an details explanation how to come out with this issue and record my drop downs also

When JMeter is not doing what it is supposed to be doing first thing to do is checking jmeter.log file for any suspicious entries. In the majority of cases you should be able to find either a root cause or at least a clue there.
The most common problem is incorrect configuration when it comes to recording SSL traffic, you will need to import JMeter's MITM certificate into your browser (or operating system), the file is called ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt and it's generated in JMeter's "bin" folder when you start the proxy server. See HTTPS recording and certificates chapter of HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder user manual entry for more details.
Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: JMeter Chrome Extension, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates and should be able to record your test script using Chrome browser only.
